# java.io.IOException: Alias name [...] does not identify a key entry

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, sse, ioexception

I have a tomcat 8 server with Eclipse luna IDE ..the server was working fine till i tried to run a particular jsp on the server, i got the "tomcat failed to start" error and someone told me to delete a .snap file in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.. after doing that tomcat isn't starting at all for any other project as well and i am getting the following errors in the console:

```
java.io.IOException: Alias name javacer does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:363)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
    ... 20 more
```

what should be done to solve this?.. would just deleting this server and setting up a new one help me?

Comment: try to delete the server and create new one

Comment: This cannot be caused by this snap file. Your application is not starting because of 2 separate issues: 1) It cannot find a key with alias "javacer" in your keystore. 2) A missing dependency: `NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log`

Comment: for 1) javacer was a security certificate which i added for a web service.. but thatshouldn't be required here as i am not connecting to any such service..

Comment: for 2) i have added all the jars files related to the server so that shouldn't come as well.. that's why i thought it might be because of the snap file